# echo command breaks lines, being used in loops

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, echo

In my file 'foo' there is a first line: 'a b', and the second line: 'c d':

```
$ cat foo
a b 
c d
```

I want to print in terminal in loop these two lines: one after another:

```
$ for i in $(cat foo); do echo $i; done
```

But in the output 'echo' command breaks the order, so instead of having:

```
a b
c d
```

I actually have:

```
a
b
c
d
```

Comment: `for i in $(cat foo)` does not loop lines but words split by your field separator (`IFS`).

Comment: So, how I can loop lines / change IFS mode to loop lines, not words?

Comment: If you tell us what you actually want to do, we can help you do it properly using  `sed` or so.,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for i in $(cat foo)` does not loop lines but words (or fields) split by your [field separator `$IFS`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184863/what-is-the-meaning-of-ifs-n-in-bash-scripting). It default to  `\n\t` (space, newline, tab).

If you change your field separator to newline only, you can use your command as is (**Disclaimer**: please read below!):

```bsh
IFS=$'\n'
for i in $(cat foo); do echo $i; done
```

You might want to make a backup of IFS to restore it later:

```bsh
OLD_IFS="$IFS"
.
.
.
IFS="$OLD_IFS"
```

Output:

```
a b
c d
```

---

However, this is considered **bad** practice.

- Bit Better: `while IFS= read -r line; do ... done < file`
- Much better: Use a dedicated tool for your task such as `grep`, `sed` or `awk`.

Please read [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: How I can use 'grep' instead?

Comment: We cannot know, because we don't know what you want to do, see my last comment on your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `while read` for this purpose

```bsh
[/tmp]$ while read line ; do echo $line ; done < foo                                     
a b
c d
```

Adding a separator for your understanding

```bsh
[/tmp]$ while read line ; do echo $line ; echo "----" ; done < foo                       
a b
----
c d
----
[/tmp]$
```

Comment: If I want to go with your solution, but also to add a conditional statement inside my for loop, then what will be "$i"?   I mean, something like this: for i in $(while read line ; do echo $line ; done < foo); do if [ grep -c a "$i" -gt 1 ]; then echo "$i";fi;done

Comment: Note that `$line` should be quoted `"$line"` for similar reasons (otherwise it will be word split into separate tokens - try with `a    b` in place of `a b` for example).

Comment: ... as well, `read` would still remove any leading whitespace and expand escape sequences by default, so more generally if you want to echo lines *exactly* you'd want `while IFS= read -r line; do ...` or (to include a possibly improperly terminated last line) `while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do ...`

Comment: @JosefKlimuk ```while read -r; do if ! grep -oe 'a' <<< "$REPLY" | sed -n 2q1; then echo "$REPLY"; fi; done < text```, `-c` only count matched lines, and since you only have one line it will never be more than 1. I like to use sed to count occurrence as it can return an exit status.